# Bash/Shell: Why am I getting the wrong output for if-else statements?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

So here's a simple script to evaluate a string length and print whether it is greater than or less than a value.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME="thisislongerthantencharacters"
echo $FILENAME
echo "$FILENAME" | wc -c 
if [ $( "$FILENAME" | wc -c ) -gt 10 ]
    then echo "FILENAME is longer than 10 characters for: $FILENAME."

elif [ $( "$FILENAME" | wc -c ) -lt 10 ]
    then echo "FILENAME is less than 10 characters for: $FILENAME."
else
    echo "None of the above"
fi
```

For some reason, I only get the output that it is less than, regardless of the string length.
Output:

```
thisislongerthantencharacters
30
FILENAME is less than 10 characters for: thisislongerthantencharacters.
```

May I know what I am doing wrong exactly? And why is the character count a bit off?

Comment: `"$FILENAME" | wc -c` _executes_ `thisislongerthantencharacters` as a command, and that probably prints nothing. Perhaps you meant `printf %s "$FILENAME" | wc -c`? But you could just use `${#FILENAME}`.

Comment: You don't need `wc` on POSIX shells, instead use `"${#FILENAME}"`.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: As an aside, you want to perform the length calculation just once, and then keep the result in a variable (especially if you are doing it inefficiently with an external process); or use a `case` statement which lets you use the command substitution as the expression to switch on.

Comment: @ChrisChance Note that the top answer to the duplicate is Bash-specific (or at least not POSIX), but your shebang says `sh` (but then you also tagged the question with Bash).